# Two column Jekyll layout, separated by tags?

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, jekyll, liquid

I'm currently working on a Jekyll blog at the moment, and I'd like to put my markdown files in this format:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">

    </div>
</div>
```

I want my code blocks in one column and everything else (text, headers, etc.) in the other column so that I have side-by-side explanations of my code.

Is there any way to do this? It seems Markdown and the Liquid templating engine is very restrictive in this regard.

Thanks!

Comment: HTML is allowed in markdown files. You can use the above HTML without any changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get desired result by combining Twitter Bootstrap with templating engine:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {{ include-code-blocks }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {{ include-texts }}
        {{ include-headers }}
        {{ include-what-you-want }}
    </div>
</div>
```

or you write them inline by enabling markdown processing inside html blocks:

```
# Apply this change to _config.yml file
kramdown:
  # parse markdown inside block-level HTML tag
  parse_block_html: true
```

And use this in markdown files:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        **some code block here**
        **another code block here**
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        **some text here**
        ##some header here
        ###something else here
    </div>
</div>
```

Info about markdown syntax:
https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet
Info about Jekyll's markdown processor: http://kramdown.gettalong.org/documentation.html

Comment: I certainly could, but from what I read, markdown will not be rendered if they are wrapped in HTML tags. Is this true?

Comment: No ! The real [Kramdown documentation is here](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/documentation.html). And Yes ! you can instruct kramdown to parse inside html block tags.

Comment: Please consider my answer as the correct one. Creating this is very well possible without using HTML in your markdown. It is a CSS problem and should be approached as such.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand, you want to take side by side, liquid/jekyll code and resulting code. You are using twitter bootstrap as css framework.

In order to instruct kramdown to parse markdown in html block tags, in `_config.yml`, add :

```
kramdown:
  # use Github Flavored Markdown
  input: GFM
  # do not replace newlines by <br>s
  hard_wrap: false
  # parse markdown inside block-level HTML tag
  parse_block_html: true
```

In marwdown files, you can now use the {% raw %}{% endraw %} tag to instruct liquid not to parse, but to print code 'as is'.

````
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
``` liquid
{% raw %}
{% if page.title == 'About' %}
page.title = {{ page.title }}
{% endif %}
{% endraw %}
```
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
{% if page.title == 'About' %}
page.title = {{ page.title }}
{% endif %}
</div>
</div>
````

**Note**: There is no indentation. it's because a four space indentation is considered as a code block by kramdown. It wraps you code in `code` tag. Not cool.

Comment: No, the OP wanted this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37093429/2397550. Nice work though...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **YES**. This is very simple. Add `float:left` to paragraphs and code blocks. Use `clear:left` on p's. Make sure there is enough space for two elements next to each other. Add `overflow:auto` to the container. Like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grqRPr.

Your Markdown file (index.md):

`````
---
layout: default
---

paragraph goes here

```` code goes here ````

paragraph goes here

```` code goes here ````
`````

Your CSS file (style.css):

```
p, pre {float: left; width: 50%;}
.container {width: 100%;}
p {clear: left;}
```

Your layout file (default.html):

```
<html>
<head>
   <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">{{ content }}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question was not how to make a two column layout with css. It's more about how markdown file content is rendered.

Comment: I know. Just add the container to your layout and generate the paragraphs and pre elements through markdown. I thought that part was obvious...

Comment: Ok, thanks. If you want me to explain the answer in more detail, please let me know. BTW, I was not addressing you specific.

Comment: Question1: where you will include CSS styles if you don't plan to use HTML at all. Question2: how would you deal with code blocks and paragraphs inside main layout?